# Performing an Advanced Stealth Man-in-The-Middle Attack in WPA2 Encrypted Wi-Fi Networks

Tags: man-in-the-middle

How feasible would it be to re-create an Advanced Stealth Man-in-The-Middle Attack as detailed in the paper linked below?

The attack exploits the "Hole 196" vulnerability and combines a WDoS with a Stealth Man-in-The-Middle attack.

Could it be done using tools readily available such as Kali Linux etc? The Hole 196 exploit requires the attacker to encrypt broadcast packets with the Group Transient Key provided by the AP - this looks to be an issue but the exploit is around 6 years old and still relevant so I would have thought there would be a tool for this attack by now.

[Advanced Stealth Man-in-The-Middle Attack in WPA2 Encrypted Wi-Fi Networks](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272385829_Advanced_Stealth_Man_in_The_Middle_Attack_in_WPA2_Encrypted_Wi-Fi_Networks)

Comment: You're not going to get a whole lot of answers to a question about a paper behind a paywall!

Comment: My bad - I have updated the link!